# Docker mySql:5.7 not running

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am a beginner with Docker. I followed a tutorial and add docker-compose.yml file.

The file looks like this -

```
version: '2'

services:
 webserver:
  build: ./docker/webserver
  image: image_name
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes:
    - /Users/user_name/Sites/project_name:/var/www/html
  links:
    - db

   db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=DB_NAME
```

I am able to run the project on the web on localhost address but the connection to mysql is not ok.
When I run 'docker ps -a' on terminal ( I am using Mac)the Status of the mysql is - Exited (1) 16 seconds ago and the PORTS is empty.

Any idea/help?

Comment: Are you sure about the volume `- ./db:/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`, if this is to keep the data, then use `- ./db:/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: Could you show me please `docker-compose logs` output

Comment: Also try to remove line `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` or set this password

Comment: @BukharovSergeyThank you! it was MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD line